# Rotate image according to EXIF orientation not working from a plugin

Tags: assets, image, upload

I am using a front-end form to upload images and store them as assets on an amazon S3 bucket.

My server has imagick installed an uses it and in my config I have "rotateImagesOnUploadByExifData" set to true.

When uploading an image I use this code to get the image and store it as an asset:

```
$file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');
$tempFilePath = $file->getTempName();
$folder = craft()->assets->findFolder(array(
    'sourceId' => craft()->config->get('assetSourceId', 'myPlugin'),
    'id'       => craft()->config->get('assetFolderId', 'myPlugin')
));            

// Turn the file into a managed asset within that folder
$response = craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath(
    $tempFilePath,
    $file->getName(),
    $folder->id,
    AssetConflictResolution::KeepBoth
);
```

Everything is working as expected, an asset is created, files get transferred to Amazon S3 bucket, but when transforming the image it shows rotated.

So I investigated:
The function 'insertFileByLocalPath' calls the function 'insertFileByPath'

In its turn this function performs the following check:

```
if (IOHelper::getFileKind(IOHelper::getExtension($localFilePath)) == 'image'
            && ImageHelper::isImageManipulatable(IOHelper::getExtension($localFilePath))
)
{
    craft()->images->cleanImage($localFilePath);
}
```

The cleanImage function should rotate the image and strip the exif data afterwards.

But since these functions work with the temporary file name (which is e.g. "/tmp/phpZB1A8y") this does not pass the test in the previous code. (it is not recognized as an image filename since it has no extension)

Any idea how I could work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to follow the same flow that Craft does - clean the filename, move to a temporary location, operate from there and afterwards delete the temporary file.

Craft has an [example](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop-v2/src/assetsourcetypes/BaseAssetSourceType.php#L166-L170) in it's codebase to help you out. Just remember to delete the temp file afterwards.

Comment: This is an excellent example. Works now, thanks!

Comment: Link is broken. Any other example?

Comment: Just fixed the link. It's Craft 2 specific, though.